# Why does a sql-statement return duplicate rows when two tables are included in the from clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have an exam on monday and I need some help to understand this sql-statement.

```
select emp.emp_pin as 'emp_pin', emp.emp_salary as 'emp_salary'
from Employer emp, Employer emp2
where emp.emp_salary = 12000
```

Why does the query return a row x amount of times(where x represents the amount of rows in the table)? When I remove Employer emp2 from the from clause it works fine.

E.G:If we have this data in the table:

```
emp_pin|emp_salary
1      |12000
2      |12000
3      |12000
```

The query will return:

```
    emp_pin|emp_salary
    1      |12000
    1      |12000
    1      |12000
    2      |12000
    2      |12000
    2      |12000
    3      |12000
    3      |12000
    3      |12000
```

Comment: Because you are doing a `cross join`, another name for a cartesian product.  As you learn SQL, just follow a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: or specify you want it DISTINCT

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay thanks. I suppose that's the reason why you should always use joins?

Comment: If you don't specify matching rows in join you get [Catersian join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join)

Comment: Add the columns for emp2 and you'll understand: SELECT emp.emp_pin as 'emp_pin', emp.emp_salary as 'emp_salary', emp2.emp_pin as 'emp2_pin', emp2.emp_salary as 'emp2_salary'

Comment: @fbiagi Yeah that clearly made it easier to understand.

Comment: @Br0therzS0ul - No, DISTINCT is not a good option here: using that you will hide the problems in the query (which will bite you later) and probably cause more work for the database server (especially if the table grows) than with the correct solution of a join.

Comment: @Br0therzS0ul No, don't do that. It just hides the problem and makes the result LOOK like an efficient query when really it's terrible.

Comment: Any reason my question got downvoted? I would like some feedback!

Comment: @Mnemonics . . . I didn't downvote your question.  But, the specific question is:  "Why does the query return a row x amount of times?".  The answer is:  "That is how SQL is defined to work".  In other words, it is like asking why SQL uses `where` instead of `filter`.  That *is* the language and what it does.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a cross product.  You have three rows in the table and you are not actually joining the two tables.

```
select emp.emp_pin as 'emp_pin', emp.emp_salary as 'emp_salary'
from Employer emp, Employer emp2
where emp.emp_salary = 12000

AND emp.EMP_PIN = emp2.EMP_PIN
```

by adding the same table in you are multiplying the rows in each table together, it is joining each row from one table to each row from the other.  so 3 rows each, 9 rows returned from the result set.  adding in a join statement will reduce the rows returned.

another way to write the query with `JOIN` syntax

```
select emp.emp_pin as 'emp_pin', emp.emp_salary as 'emp_salary'
from Employer emp JOIN Employer emp2
ON emp.EMP_PIN = emp2.EMP_PIN
where emp.emp_salary = 12000
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have already enlightened, using a Cartesian products gives you the duplicate rows. The query you need using joins is this:

```
select emp.emp_pin as 'emp_pin', emp.emp_salary as 'emp_salary'
from Employer emp join Employer emp2 on emp.emp_pin=emp2.emp_pin
where emp.emp_salary = 12000;
```